# Creating a Class from a Variable and Using it to Extend Another Class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm using a plugin in wordpress which requires each shortcode I define to be used to extend a function. I've set up my code in a way which means it's going to be difficult to go back and extend all the classes. For example, the plugin expects this:

```
class WPBakeryShortCode_myCode extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {}
```

I want to replace 'myCode' with a variable, because I have all the possible codes stored in an array. so I want to have

```
class WPBakeryShortCode_$customCode extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {}
```

i.e. using a variable to define a class which then extends another class. Every way I've tried this I've gotten an error. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: If all those classes then have the same functionality, why even have them? Just pass your identifier as a constructor argument, if you later need to make a distinction.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Ask yourself what you'll be using these generated classes for. As they can't be changed at runtime, they'll most probably all share the same behavior. Meaning, the `$customeCode` you want to use in the class name is the only meaningful distinction and as such should be *data*. For example https://3v4l.org/2RIi0 or if you just want a common place to store those codes, use constants: https://3v4l.org/cUWLB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant instantiate one at runtime from a variable.

There's no recommended way to dynamically do that because the generated class has to be instantiated before the variable is evaluated

Using `Eval` is bad practice and  its **not recommended**, if you want to know how here is example

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php

class A { }
class B { 
     function iamB(){
         print "From B".PHP_EOL;
     }
}

$myvariable = 'B';  


$code =<<<EOF
  class C extends $myvariable { 
    public static function bar(){
      print "not recommended".PHP_EOL; 
    }
  }
EOF;

eval( $code );

C::iamB();
C::bar();

?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
From B
not recommended
```